# DVTAssertions：(null) deviceType from UDID was NULL when -platform called

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I'm developing an app in Flutter.
I tried to build the app, but I get the following error and can't run the app.

```
xcodebuild[80270:554507]  DVTAssertions: Warning in
    /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTiOSFrameworks/DVTiOSFrameworks...
    Details:  (null) deviceType from <UDID> was NULL when -platform called.
    Object:   <DTDKMobileDeviceToken: <TOKEN>>
    Method:   -platform
    Thread:   <NSThread: <TOKEN>>{number = 2, name = (null)}
    Please file a bug at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
```

Answer (score 0):

I currently face the same issue.
I can't run my Flutter app from IntelliJ on an iPhone 13 simulator.
However, **I'm able to run the app directly from XCode**.

I tried to run `flutter clean`, but that didn't help.

---

@Olle Kyrychenko suggested the following steps in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59921997/could-not-build-the-application-for-the-simulator-error-launching-application-o) in case the Flutter app can't run on a simulator.

1. `rm ios/Podfile`

Upgrade your packages:

- `pub upgrade`
- `pub run`

And update your podfile:

- `cd ios`
- `pod update`

Then clean and run:

- `flutter clean`
- `flutter run`

---

I haven't tested the above because I have some packages that can not be upgraded at the moment, but it might be the solution to the issue.

If I'll find something, I'll update my post.

Comment: Hi George, did you find a solution for this issue?

Comment: Hi @WaelFadlÃllåh,

Unfortunately, I can't help you, it was such a long time ago.
 
I think it should be possible by now to run Flutter apps on an iOS simulator from IntelliJ, but I haven't been working with Flutter and mobile for almost a year now.

As far as I remember, I used XCode in most cases to run my Flutter apps on iOS. I remember that I faced a lot of iOS errors, so I had to use Xcode on the first-run, and IntelliJ worked afterward for a day, or a week. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯