# I can't solve 'Could not build the application for the simulator. '

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart

Yesterday, I created a flutter project named sample1.
and I worked fine.
but when I tried to open the file today and try to run it, I got an error.

the log says

```
Running "flutter pub get" in sample1...                            603ms
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 8 in debug mode...
Running pod install...                                           1,313ms
Running Xcode build...                                                  
Xcode build done.                                           11.8s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳

    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Analyzing workspace
    note: Constructing build description
    note: Build preparation complete
    warning: Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID. To resolve
    this, select a development team in the Runner editor. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 8.
```

I think I have tried everything written here, except the ones like

```
pub upgrade
pub run
```

because it says

```
zsh: command not found: pub
```

[Could not build the application for the simulator. Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro Max](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59921997/could-not-build-the-application-for-the-simulator-error-launching-application-o)

The android version is working fine.
Please kindly help me.
Thank you

EDIT**
I just created a new project and it seemed to be working fine but I am afraid it won't work next time I open it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before Anything you will first need to Run a successful Xcode build on your desired iOS device or Simulator **directly from Xcode**!

If you've successfully done so head over to : [the instructions to run with Hot Reload⚡️ on iOS from VsCode & Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68452356/12548494)

If not - Follow this 8 steps to getting your Xcode Build Up & Running ->

###### 1. Open Xcode - do all the classic Set Up (Signing in with your [dev account](https://developer.apple.com/) as a Team & choosing a UNIQUE bundle Identifier)

[image: S.Shot Xcode Signing & Capabilities]

###### 2. **If you don't have [cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/) Installed on your Mac :**

From terminal `cd ~`

then : **for M1 Mac run the following :**

```
arch -x86_64 sudo gem install ffi
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

while **for intel macs just run :**

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

###### 3. Now once you have cocoapods installed on your machine

```
cd yourflutterprojectroot

flutter clean
flutter pub get
```

###### 4. Update & install pods :

**for M1 Macs** :

```
cd ios
arch -x86_64 pod update
pod install
arch -x86_64 pod update
```

**for intel macs :**

```
cd ios
pod update
pod install
pod update
```

###### 5. Connect your iPhone (if you want to run on real device)

In your iPhone Settings - set Auto-Lock to Never (& Unlock it !) - Connect your iPhone or iPad to Mac **with USB cable** & Accept Prompt "Trust Computer" on the iPhone

[image: S.Shot iPhone Prompt]

###### 6. Run Xcode Build from Xcode make sure to Select your device or simulator

[image: Select device in Xcode & Run]

After running this alert should prompt select `Ok`

[image: S.Shot Xcode Could not Launch "Runner"]

*if this alert didn't prompt & build failed totally Try setting your `Runner > Info > Configurations` [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pip3q.png) but first try to see if you can do step 7 - if you can do it don't change anything*

###### 7. In your *iPhone Settings* > General > A New Menu will have appeared - Navigate to it & Click « Verify App » or « Accept »

[image: Developer iPhone Settings]

###### 8. Now **Run Xcode Build Again** - it should build

— *Xcode Build is done*

✨

---

Now -

You've done everything successfully ✨ - congrats - it works -

- But what if you wanted to run **directly** from **VSCode or Android Studio** ?

It would make to long of a post - so i've split my answer for this second question :

[find here the instructions to run with Hot Reload⚡️ on iOS from VsCode & Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68452356/12548494)

See you there !

Comment: Thank you I tried flutter pub get and flutter run but I still get the same error

Comment: I’ve updated answer let me know if you still have issues 

Comment: Probably this is so basic so I feel bad but I don't understand `do all the classic Set Up` part. should I open the project on xcode and setup? because I couldn't open it with xcode.

Comment: Sorry I think I could set up the project on xcode

Comment: I am sorry but I still get the same error. I tried to set the signing and capabilities on xcode too .

Comment: it works fine on xcode but doesn't work on my vscode I don't know what to do .

Comment: i've edited my post ! you should now be able to do the Full Set Up !  enjoy !

Answer (score 2):

Run command like  `flutter pub upgrade` not just pub upgrade.

Comment: Thank you. I've just try `rm ios/Podfile` and `flutter pub upgrade` but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

> Your first question was on *running your flutter app on iOS* - you've done so by [running your first Xcode Build](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68448643/12548494) : )
>
> Now - I'll answer for both VSCode & Android Studio - your second question :

#### How do i run my Flutter App with Hot Reload ⚡️ on a Real iOS device or Simulator ?

To get started you will first need to follow the instruction in [my first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68448643/12548494) & run a **successful Xcode Build** - directly from Xcode

*Once you've done so follow this steps :*

1. - *Make sure your device is still connected & unlocked* - Run `flutter devices` in Terminal :

It will tell you if your device or Simulator is detected (it should be since you've **just** done a successful Xcode build)

2. Open back your flutter project in VsCode or Android Studio & *make sure your device is still unlocked - open a new simulator only if you want to run on Simulator*

#### Do a first Hot Reload⚡️ using Terminal Commands :

Run `flutter run` in your flutter project root
or
run `flutter run -d yourDeviceID`
if it does not directly run on your iOS device or Simulator

*You will find your iOS device ID here :*

[image: Picture of Menu to find Device ID]

Select `Add Additional Simulators`

[image: Picture Device ID]

After running `flutter run` or `flutter run -d yourDeviceID` an error will prompt if it's your first time running

[image: Error Allow Developer to open App]

Press `Cancel` & go to your Mac > Systems Preferences > Security & Privacy - & allow the file to execute

[image: Security & Privacy Screen]

then wait a bit the app might launch on it's own or try `flutter run` again or `flutter run -d yourDeviceID`

Once successful you can now use Hot Reload by pressing r in terminal

- to Hot Reload **On Save** in VsCode or Android Studio - follow bellow instructions :

[image: HotReload Tab]

#### Hot Reload⚡️Using VsCode :

Press <kbd>F8</kbd> or Select ▷ « Start Debugging » in main.dart

That’s it ! You now have the power of Hot Reload⚡️ with VsCode on a *physical* device !

#### Hot Reload⚡️on Android Studio :

Select your iOS device & run *(it should appear if you've followed everyting correctly)*

---

Answer (score 1):

You should try go to **flutter/bin/cache** delete cache folder inside bin folder then run **flutter upgrade** then **flutter doctor** and rerun your app

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I though it could work but it didn't. it still has the same error.

Comment: the error occurred probably because I didn't set anything for iOS on Xcode. as the other person told me I set an identifier and it worked.