# Running iOS on Flutter when clone from GitHub

Tags: ios, flutter

I'm a beginner of Flutter trying to clone from this GitHub.
https://github.com/MarcusNg/flutter_instagram/tree/47-null-safety

When I build this on my end, I get this error message. I'm on M1 Mac, so that might be an issue. Can someone help me on this? I went over the below articles but didn't help.

[Could not build the application for the simulator. Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro Max](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59921997/could-not-build-the-application-for-the-simulator-error-launching-application-o)

[https://fluttercorner.com/could-not-find-included-file-pods-target-support-files-pods-runner-pods-runner-debug-xcconfig/#:~:text=target%20'Runner'](https://fluttercorner.com/could-not-find-included-file-pods-target-support-files-pods-runner-pods-runner-debug-xcconfig/#:%7E:text=target%20%27Runner%27))%3F-,to%20Solve%20error%3A%20could%20not%20find%20included%20file%20'Pods%2F,and%20re%2Drun%20your%20app.

---

Error message

Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 13 in debug mode...
Running pod install...                                              8.2s
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           20.6s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
objc[99064]: Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both
/usr/lib/libamsupport.dylib (0x21ac67678) and
/Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice
(0x1059dc2c8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[99064]: Class AMSupportURLSession is implemented in both /usr/lib/libamsupport.dylib
(0x21ac676c8) and
/Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice
(0x1059dc318). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
** BUILD FAILED **

Xcode's output:
↳
Writing result bundle at path:
/var/folders/v9/8dgxpk8d2_n1d1ff0mh4wf_m0000gn/T/flutter_tools.4T2ST9/flutter_ios_build_temp_dir0
1QNZP/temporary_xcresult_bundle

```
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path_provider_windows-0.0.4+3/lib/src/path_provider_
windows_real.dart:126:25: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart'
 ('../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named
'addressOf'.
          knownFolderID.addressOf, KF_FLAG_DEFAULT, NULL, pathPtrPtr);
                        ^^^^^^^^^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/platform-2.2.1/lib/src/interface/local_platform.dart
:45:41: Error: Member not found: 'packageRoot'.
  String get packageRoot => io.Platform.packageRoot;
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:1067:7: Error: The
getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'LOGFONT'.
 - 'LOGFONT' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart'
 ('../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named
'addressOf'.
      addressOf.cast<Uint8>().elementAt(28).cast<Utf16>();
      ^^^^^^^^^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:1112:29: Error: The
getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'ENUMLOGFONTEX'.
 - 'ENUMLOGFONTEX' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart'
 ('../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named
'addressOf'.
  LOGFONT get elfLogFont => addressOf.cast<LOGFONT>().ref;
                            ^^^^^^^^^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:1114:29: Error: The
getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'ENUMLOGFONTEX'.
 - 'ENUMLOGFONTEX' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart'
 ('../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named
'addressOf'.
  String get elfFullName => addressOf
                            ^^^^^^^^^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:1120:26: Error: The
getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'ENUMLOGFONTEX'.
 - 'ENUMLOGFONTEX' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart'
 ('../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named
'addressOf'.
  String get elfStyle => addressOf
                         ^^^^^^^^^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:1126:27: Error: The
getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'ENUMLOGFONTEX'.
 - 'ENUMLOGFONTEX' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart'
 ('../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named
'addressOf'.
  String get elfScript => addressOf
                          ^^^^^^^^^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2688:7: Error: The
getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'OSVERSIONINFO'.
 - 'OSVERSIONINFO' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart'
 ('../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named
'addressOf'.
      addressOf.cast<Uint8>().elementAt(20).cast<Utf16>().unpackString(128);
      ^^^^^^^^^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2699:11: Error: The
getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'OSVERSIONINFO'.
 - 'OSVERSIONINFO' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart'
 ('../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named
'addressOf'.
        ..addressOf.cast<Uint8>().elementAt(20).value = 0;
          ^^^^^^^^^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2744:24: Error: The
getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO'.
 - 'BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart'
 ('../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named
'addressOf'.
  String get szName => addressOf
                       ^^^^^^^^^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2837:7: Error: The
getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO'.
 - 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart'
 ('../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named
'addressOf'.
      addressOf.cast<Uint8>().elementAt(BTH_MAX_PIN_SIZE).value;
      ^^^^^^^^^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2840:5: Error: The
getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO'.
 - 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart'
 ('../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named
'addressOf'.
    addressOf.cast<Uint8>().elementAt(BTH_MAX_PIN_SIZE).value =
    ^^^^^^^^^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2845:28: Error: The
getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO'.
 - 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart'
 ('../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named
'addressOf'.
      String.fromCharCodes(addressOf.cast<Uint8>().asTypedList(pinLength));
                           ^^^^^^^^^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2853:7: Error: The
getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO'.
 - 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart'
 ('../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named
'addressOf'.
      addressOf.cast<Uint8>().elementAt(idx).value = pinData[idx];
      ^^^^^^^^^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/com/combase.dart:38:31: Error:
The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart'
 ('../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named
'addressOf'.
  final iid = GUID.allocate().addressOf;
                              ^^^^^^^^^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/com/combase.dart:56:33: Error:
The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart'
 ('../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named
'addressOf'.
  final clsid = GUID.allocate().addressOf;
                                ^^^^^^^^^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/winrt/winrt_helpers.dart:86:40:
Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart'
 ('../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named
'addressOf'.
  final riidCalendar = GUID.allocate().addressOf;
                                       ^^^^^^^^^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IDesktopWallpaper.dart
:197:38: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'COMObject'.
 - 'COMObject' is from 'package:win32/src/com/combase.dart'
 ('../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/com/combase.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named
'addressOf'.
    final ptr = COMObject.allocate().addressOf;
                                     ^^^^^^^^^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IDesktopWallpaper.dart
:200:49: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart'
 ('../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named
'addressOf'.
        GUID.fromString(CLSID_DesktopWallpaper).addressOf,
                                                ^^^^^^^^^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IDesktopWallpaper.dart
:203:48: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart'
 ('../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named
'addressOf'.
        GUID.fromString(IID_IDesktopWallpaper).addressOf,
                                               ^^^^^^^^^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IFileOpenDialog.dart:5
8:38: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'COMObject'.
 - 'COMObject' is from 'package:win32/src/com/combase.dart'
 ('../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/com/combase.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named
'addressOf'.
    final ptr = COMObject.allocate().addressOf;
                                     ^^^^^^^^^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IFileOpenDialog.dart:6
1:47: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart'
 ('../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named
'addressOf'.
        GUID.fromString(CLSID_FileOpenDialog).addressOf,
                                              ^^^^^^^^^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IFileOpenDialog.dart:6
4:46: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart'
 ('../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named
'addressOf'.
        GUID.fromString(IID_IFileOpenDialog).addressOf,
                                             ^^^^^^^^^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IFileSaveDialog.dart:9
9:38: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'COMObject'.
 - 'COMObject' is from 'package:win32/src/com/combase.dart'
 ('../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/com/combase.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named
'addressOf'.
    final ptr = COMObject.allocate().addressOf;
                                     ^^^^^^^^^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IFileSaveDialog.dart:1
02:47: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart'
 ('../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named
'addressOf'.
        GUID.fromString(CLSID_FileSaveDialog).addressOf,
                                              ^^^^^^^^^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IFileSaveDialog.dart:1
05:46: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart'
 ('../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named
'addressOf'.
        GUID.fromString(IID_IFileSaveDialog).addressOf,
                                             ^^^^^^^^^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IKnownFolderManager.da
rt:164:38: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'COMObject'.
 - 'COMObject' is from 'package:win32/src/com/combase.dart'
 ('../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/com/combase.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named
'addressOf'.
    final ptr = COMObject.allocate().addressOf;
                                     ^^^^^^^^^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IKnownFolderManager.da
rt:167:51: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart'
 ('../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named
'addressOf'.
        GUID.fromString(CLSID_KnownFolderManager).addressOf,
                                                  ^^^^^^^^^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IKnownFolderManager.da
rt:170:50: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart'
 ('../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named
'addressOf'.
        GUID.fromString(IID_IKnownFolderManager).addressOf,
                                                 ^^^^^^^^^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/INetworkListManager.da
rt:128:38: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'COMObject'.
 - 'COMObject' is from 'package:win32/src/com/combase.dart'
 ('../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/com/combase.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named
'addressOf'.
    final ptr = COMObject.allocate().addressOf;
                                     ^^^^^^^^^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/INetworkListManager.da
rt:131:51: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart'
 ('../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named
'addressOf'.
        GUID.fromString(CLSID_NetworkListManager).addressOf,
                                                  ^^^^^^^^^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/INetworkListManager.da
rt:134:50: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart'
 ('../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named
'addressOf'.
        GUID.fromString(IID_INetworkListManager).addressOf,
                                                 ^^^^^^^^^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IWbemLocator.dart:82:3
8: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'COMObject'.
 - 'COMObject' is from 'package:win32/src/com/combase.dart'
 ('../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/com/combase.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named
'addressOf'.
    final ptr = COMObject.allocate().addressOf;
                                     ^^^^^^^^^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IWbemLocator.dart:84:6
8: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart'
 ('../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named
'addressOf'.
    final hr = CoCreateInstance(GUID.fromString(CLSID_WbemLocator).addressOf,
                                                                   ^^^^^^^^^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/generated/IWbemLocator.dart:85:6
4: Error: The getter 'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'GUID'.
 - 'GUID' is from 'package:win32/src/structs.dart'
 ('../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named
'addressOf'.
        nullptr, CLSCTX_ALL, GUID.fromString(IID_IWbemLocator).addressOf, ptr);
                                                               ^^^^^^^^^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/utf8.dart:63:33: Error: The getter
'addressOf' isn't defined for the class 'Utf8'.
 - 'Utf8' is from 'package:ffi/src/utf8.dart'
 ('../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/utf8.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named
'addressOf'.
  String toString() => fromUtf8(addressOf);
                                ^^^^^^^^^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/utf16.dart:16:7: Error: Struct
'Utf16' is empty. Empty structs and unions are undefined behavior.
class Utf16 extends Struct {
      ^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/utf8.dart:23:7: Error: Struct
'Utf8' is empty. Empty structs and unions are undefined behavior.
class Utf8 extends Struct {
      ^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2999:7: Error:
Struct 'NLM_SIMULATED_PROFILE_INFO' is empty. Empty structs and unions are undefined behavior.
class NLM_SIMULATED_PROFILE_INFO extends Struct {}
      ^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2992:7: Error:
Struct 'STATSTG' is empty. Empty structs and unions are undefined behavior.
class STATSTG extends Struct {}
      ^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2985:7: Error:
Struct 'CLSID' is empty. Empty structs and unions are undefined behavior.
class CLSID extends Struct {}
      ^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2978:7: Error:
Struct 'SAFEARRAY' is empty. Empty structs and unions are undefined behavior.
class SAFEARRAY extends Struct {}
      ^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2973:7: Error:
Struct 'PROPVARIANT' is empty. Empty structs and unions are undefined behavior.
class PROPVARIANT extends Struct {}
      ^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2966:7: Error:
Struct 'PROPERTYKEY' is empty. Empty structs and unions are undefined behavior.
class PROPERTYKEY extends Struct {}
      ^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2960:7: Error:
Struct 'EXCEPINFO' is empty. Empty structs and unions are undefined behavior.
class EXCEPINFO extends Struct {}
      ^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:2835:7: Error:
Struct 'BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO' is empty. Empty structs and unions are undefined behavior.
class BLUETOOTH_PIN_INFO extends Struct {
      ^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-1.7.4/lib/src/structs.dart:1111:7: Error:
Struct 'ENUMLOGFONTEX' is empty. Empty structs and unions are undefined behavior.
class ENUMLOGFONTEX extends Struct {
      ^
../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ffi-0.1.3/lib/src/allocation.dart:47:33: Error:
Expected type 'T' to be a valid and instantiated subtype of 'NativeType'.
  final int totalSize = count * sizeOf<T>();
                                ^
Failed to package /Users/YN/development/flutter_instagram.
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
note: Using new build system
note: Planning
note: Build preparation complete
note: Building targets in dependency order
/Users/YN/development/flutter_instagram/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator
deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported
deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.2.99. (in target 'nanopb' from project 'Pods')
/Users/YN/development/flutter_instagram/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator
deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported
deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.2.99. (in target 'leveldb-library' from project 'Pods')
/Users/YN/development/flutter_instagram/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator
deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported
deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.2.99. (in target 'abseil' from project 'Pods')
/Users/YN/development/flutter_instagram/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator
deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported
deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.2.99. (in target 'TOCropViewController' from project
'Pods')
/Users/YN/development/flutter_instagram/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator
deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported
deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.2.99. (in target 'FMDB' from project 'Pods')
/Users/YN/development/flutter_instagram/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator
deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported
deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.2.99. (in target 'gRPC-C++' from project 'Pods')
/Users/YN/development/flutter_instagram/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator
deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported
deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.2.99. (in target 'FirebaseFirestore' from project 'Pods')
/Users/YN/development/flutter_instagram/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator
deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported
deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.2.99. (in target 'Firebase' from project 'Pods')

Result bundle written to path:
    /var/folders/v9/8dgxpk8d2_n1d1ff0mh4wf_m0000gn/T/flutter_tools.4T2ST9/flutter_ios_build_temp_dir0
    1QNZP/temporary_xcresult_bundle
```

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 13.

Comment: did you try `Flutter clean` and `Flutter pub get`?

Comment: @Usamamajid Thanks for your comment. Yes, I did, but doesn't help me