# Can't run Flutter app on simulator after upgrading XCode to 14.3 because of missing libarclite_iphonesimulator.a file

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, visual-studio-code

I'm using VSCode to develop my Flutter app, and I can't run my Flutter app on simulator (iOS 15, IPhone11) after I upgraded XCode to latest verison (14.3). Here is the error message:

```
Error (Xcode): File not found: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc/libarclite_iphonesimulator.a

Error (Xcode): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Could not build the application for the simulator.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Missing file (libarclite\_iphoneos.a) in Xcode 14.3 after update flutter and xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75894992/missing-file-libarclite-iphoneos-a-in-xcode-14-3-after-update-flutter-and-xcod)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have updated the Pods libraries Minimum Deployments 11.0

Make sure all the library Minimum Deployments Versions should be above 11.0, Then it worked for me.

[image]

OR

Add the below code in the end of the Podfile and do pod install.

```html
post_install do |installer|
  installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
    project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '11.0'
         end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 21):

After installing 14.3 I had to modify my `ios/Podfile` to get my project running again:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end

  installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
    project.targets.each do |target|
            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '11.0'
            end
        end
    end
end
```

The issue is that, the deployment targets for iOS must be 11.0 or higher for iOS 16.4.

See: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/725300

UPDATE: As mentioned by @danielrosero, you need to run `pod install` again, after editing `iOS/Podfile`.

Comment: Thanks! It solved my build issue but I had to set mine to 13.0, because of some dependencies

Comment: Just to add that after putting this block of code, you need to run `pod install` again.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have update the pod files after that follow the steps that are mentioned below:

**Step 1**

Track the issue cased by library.If you look at the screenshot I got an error for FMDB Pod:

[image]

**Step 2**

we need to change the iOS version on effected pod file because new xCode not support below iOS 11.0
[image]

Step 3
Extra Step you may also face a build distribution error after updating pods. Do this to avoid that issue.

Change Distribution setting on Target Pod.

[image]

Rebuild your app again on Xcode.

upvote my answer if it's helpful

Comment: This works perfectly for me. I have other pod issues, but I follow the same steps and it works. Thanks